# Deploying Win Server 2008 R2 in VBox (Linux Host): Unknown Error 0xc00000000025

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

Title says it all, but I'm running into an error deploying Windows Server 2008 R2 on a Linux host, inside VBox.  This is a during-installation issue, which is that it gets to the "Loading Windows..." screen with the Windows logo on it, then during that process triggers an "Unknown Error" Black Screen of Failure, stating "Encountered an unknown error" with an error code of 0xc0000025.

Any suggestions to how I should continue?

Comment: The original 0x0000025 error is no longer occurring.  The new error is 0xc00000025.  Any ideas anyone>